# Node Red. Extracting bytes from a buffer

Tags: buffer, node-red, lora

I have a collection of sensors using LoRaWan to connect via ttn to a Node Red application and this is working very well.

For bandwidth economy I want to try not using my present payload configuration and just transmit an array of 8 bytes.

If I do this the output from the ttn uplink node is `msg.payload:buffer[8]` followed by e.g. `[10, 175, 0, 232, 0, 4, 9, 1]`.

In Node Red how do I extract the individual bytes from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the function node and interact with the buffer as you would with normal javascript code. The API doc for the buffer object can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/buffer.html)

You can also look at the [node-red-contrib-binary](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-binary) node which lets you specific field types and names and it will build a JSON object from the byte stream.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about node-red-contrib-binary and it hadn't put in appearance during my searches. I've installed and it's doing just what I need,